# MySQL query performance problem - INNER JOIN, ORDER BY, DESC

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have got this query:

```
                SELECT 
                t.type_id, t.product_id, u.account_id, t.name, u.username

                FROM
                types AS t

                INNER JOIN
                ( SELECT user_id, username, account_id 
                  FROM users WHERE account_id=$account_id ) AS u

                ON 

                t.user_id = u.user_id 

                ORDER BY 
                t.type_id DESC
```

**1st question:**

It takes around 30seconds to do this at the moment with only 18k records in types table.

The only indexes at the moment are only a primary indexes with just id.

Would the long time be caused by a lack of more indexes? Or would it be more to do with the structure of this query?

**2nd question:**

How can I add the LIMIT so I only get 100 records with the highest type_id?

Comment: That can't be the real query. You've got a `p` table alias, but aren't aliasing any tables to `p`.

Comment: I simplicated the query, to make it clearer, sorry, i have just corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the results, I think it is a 100 times faster if you don't make a sub-select of your users table. It is not needed at all in this case.

You can just add LIMIT 100 to get only the first 100 results (or less if there aren't a 100).

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS /* Calculate the total number of rows, without the LIMIT */
  t.type_id, t.product_id, u.account_id, t.name, u.username
FROM
  types t
  INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE
  u.account_id = $account_id
ORDER BY
  t.type_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Then, execute a second query to get the total number of rows that is calculated.

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try this. How easy is it to get 100 penultimate type_id's ? BTW. Sorry for a mistake, instead of "p" should be "t", please see the edit above

Comment: And I copied that mistake. Well you get the point. :) I had too look up 'penultimate', but now I did, I'm still not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean pagination. If LIMIT 100 takes the range: 100 to 0, How can I dig out range: 200 to 100 ? :)

Comment: LIMIT allows two parameters, so to say. You can specify both a count and an offset, which is indeed great for pagination. http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: I tried your query and it doesn't return anything, even if I remove the limit

Comment: I do apologize GolezTrol, your query does work perfectly :) Thank you very much for your help. Oh, and, what do you mean by "you get a point"?

Comment: When we do the LIMIT, is there any way of also getting a total number of records somehow in the same query? or should I do a separate query for just that?

Comment: With "You get the point", I meant you will understand what the solution in this query is, even though I accidentally used the alias 'p' instead of 't' in the join. Fixed this now..

Comment: To get the total number of rows without the limit, you can add the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` directive to the query, as demonstrated in my modified answer. This isn't a field, and will not return an value, but after executing the query, you can executed a simple second query to retrieve the calculated count: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`.

Answer (score 0):

That sub select on MySQL is going to slow down your query. I'm assuming that this

```
SELECT user_id, username, account_id 
FROM users WHERE account_id=$account_id
```

doesn't return many rows at all. If that's the case then the sub select alone won't explain the delay you're seeing.

Try throwing an index on user_id in your types table. Without it, you're doing a full table scan of 18k records for each record returned by that sub select.

Inner join the users table and add that index and I bet you see a huge increase in speed.

Comment: the sub select returns around 14k rows

Comment: Do you mean a single index on user_id or a complex index of ( type_id, user_id ) apart of the primary index of type_id, which is there ?

Comment: A single index on user_id since that's the field you're joining on.

Comment: The sub select creates an in memory "derived" table which has no indexes. You're joining it on a column in another table which also has no indexes, so it's scanning (size of derived table) x (size of users) rows. Based on what you've said, that's around 250 million rows being scanned. I'm not surprised it's taking 30 seconds.

Comment: Nice :) So how should I change this query round in your opinion for best performance?

Comment: GolexTrol's answer has a good example of inner joining that table. I'd do it the same way, just make sure to also throw an index on types.user_id.